# convert recycleview volley activity to fragment error

Tags: android, android-fragments, scrollview, android-volley, android-recyclerview

i've got this null pointer exeception error

```
03-10 14:08:27.510 9297-9297/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL 

    EXCEPTION: main
                                                     Process: com.anakacara.anakacara, PID: 9297
                                                     java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                         at com.anakacara.anakacara.Fragment.EventFragment.getDataFromServer(EventFragment.java:163)
                                                         at com.anakacara.anakacara.Fragment.EventFragment.getData(EventFragment.java:192)
                                                         at com.anakacara.anakacara.Fragment.EventFragment.onCreateView(EventFragment.java:127)
                                                         at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1962)
                                                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
                                                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1248)
                                                         at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738)
```

here is my customVolleyRequest code

```
public class CustomVolleyRequest {

    private static CustomVolleyRequest customVolleyRequest;
    private static Context context;
    private RequestQueue requestQueue;
    private ImageLoader imageLoader;

    private CustomVolleyRequest(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        this.requestQueue = getRequestQueue();

        imageLoader = new ImageLoader(requestQueue,
                new ImageLoader.ImageCache() {
                    private final LruCache<String, Bitmap>
                            cache = new LruCache<String, Bitmap>(20);

                    @Override
                    public Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
                        return cache.get(url);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void putBitmap(String url, Bitmap bitmap) {
                        cache.put(url, bitmap);
                    }
                });
    }

    public static synchronized CustomVolleyRequest getInstance(Context context) {
        if (customVolleyRequest == null) {
            customVolleyRequest = new CustomVolleyRequest(context);
        }
        return customVolleyRequest;
    }

    public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
        if (requestQueue == null) {
            Cache cache = new DiskBasedCache(context.getCacheDir(), 10 * 1024 * 1024);
            Network network = new BasicNetwork(new HurlStack());
            requestQueue = new RequestQueue(cache, network);
            requestQueue.start();
        }
        return requestQueue;
    }

    public ImageLoader getImageLoader() {
        return imageLoader;
    }
}
```

this is my appconfig class for storing tag

```
public class AppConfig {
    // Server user login url
    public static String URL_LOGIN = "http://192.168.0.13:80/task_manager/v1/login";

    // Server user register url
    public static String URL_REGISTER = "http://192.168.0.13/task_manager/v1/register";

    //URL of my even
    public static final String DATA_URL = "http://192.168.0.13/task_manager/v1/even/";

    //Tags for my JSON

    public static final String TAG_IMAGE_URL = "gambar";
    public static final String TAG_JUDUL = "judul";
    public static final String TAG_DESKRIPSI = "deskripsi";
    public static final String TAG_DUIT = "duit";
    public static final String TAG_PERSEN = "persen";
    public static final String TAG_SISA_HARI = "sisahari";
}
```

this is getter and setter

```
public class Event {
        //Data Variables
        private String imageUrl;
        private String name;
        private String rank;
        private int realName;
        private int createdBy;
        private int firstAppearance;
        //private ArrayList<String> powers;

        //Getters and Setters
        public String getImageUrl() {
            return imageUrl;
        }

        public void setImageUrl(String imageUrl) {
            this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
        }

        //GET AND SET JUDUL
        public String getJudul() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setJudul(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        //GET AND SET DESKRIPSI
        public String getDeskripsi() {
            return rank;
        }

        public void setDeskripsi(String rank) {
            this.rank = rank;
        }

        //GET AND SET DUIT

        public int getDuit() {
            return realName;
        }

        public void setDuit(int realName) {
            this.realName = realName;
        }

        //GET AND SET PERSEN

        public int getPersen() {
            return createdBy;
        }

        public void setPersen(int createdBy) {
            this.createdBy = createdBy;
        }

        //GET AND SET SISA HARI

        public int getSisaHari() {
            return firstAppearance;
        }

        public void setSisaHari(int firstAppearance) {
            this.firstAppearance = firstAppearance;
        }


    }
```

and this is my main fragment

```
public class EventFragment extends Fragment {
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    //Creating a List of event
    private List<Event> listEvent;

    //Creating Views
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
    private int requestCount = 1;
    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;
    private RequestQueue requestQueue;
    public EventFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment EventFragment.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static EventFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        EventFragment fragment = new EventFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    private final RecyclerView.OnScrollListener onScrollListener = new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(final RecyclerView recyclerView, final int newState) {
            // code
            if (isLastItemDisplaying(recyclerView)) {
                //Calling the method getdata again
                getData();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onScrolled(final RecyclerView recyclerView, final int dx, final int dy) {
            // code
            if (isLastItemDisplaying(recyclerView)) {
                //Calling the method getdata again
                getData();
            }
        }
    };
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View x =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_event,null);;
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) x.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);


        //Initializing our event list
        listEvent = new ArrayList<>();
        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity().getApplication());
        //Calling method to get data
        getData();
        recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(rVOnScrollListener);
        adapter = new CardAdapter(listEvent, getActivity().getApplication());

        //Adding adapter to recyclerview
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
//        RecyclerView.ItemAnimator itemAnimator = new DefaultItemAnimator();
//        itemAnimator.setAddDuration(1000);
//        itemAnimator.setRemoveDuration(1000);
//        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(itemAnimator);
//        recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerTouchListener(getActivity(), recyclerView, new ClickListener() {
//            @Override
//            public void onClick(View view, int position) {
//                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), DetailEvent.class);
//                intent.putExtra("event_judul", listEvent.get(position).getJudul()); //you can name the keys whatever you like
//                intent.putExtra("event_deskripsi", listEvent.get(position).getDeskripsi()); //note that all these values have to be primitive (i.e boolean, int, double, String, etc.)
//                intent.putExtra("event_duit", listEvent.get(position).getDuit());
//                intent.putExtra("event_persen", listEvent.get(position).getPersen()); //note that all these values have to be primitive (i.e boolean, int, double, String, etc.)
//                intent.putExtra("event_sisa_hari", listEvent.get(position).getSisaHari());
//                intent.putExtra("event_image", listEvent.get(position).getImageUrl());
//                startActivity(intent);
//            }
//
//            @Override
//            public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {
//                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Kepencet Lama " + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
//            }
//        }));

        return x;
    }
    private JsonArrayRequest getDataFromServer(int requestCount) {
        //Initializing ProgressBar
        final ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);

        //Displaying Progressbar
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        getActivity().getParent().setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);

        //JsonArrayRequest of volley
        JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(AppConfig.DATA_URL + String.valueOf(requestCount),
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        //Calling method parseData to parse the json response
                        parseData(response);
                        //Hiding the progressbar
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        //If an error occurs that means end of the list has reached
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No More Items Available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

        //Returning the request
        return jsonArrayRequest;
    }

    private void getData(){
        //Adding the method to the queue by calling the method getDataFromServer
        requestQueue.add(getDataFromServer(requestCount));
        //Incrementing the request counter
        requestCount++;

    }

    //This method will parse json data
    private void parseData(JSONArray array){
        for(int i = 0; i<array.length(); i++) {
            Event event = new Event();
            JSONObject json = null;
            try {
                json = array.getJSONObject(i);

                event.setJudul(json.getString(AppConfig.TAG_JUDUL));
                event.setDeskripsi(json.getString(AppConfig.TAG_DESKRIPSI));
                event.setDuit(json.getInt(AppConfig.TAG_DUIT));
                event.setPersen(json.getInt(AppConfig.TAG_PERSEN));
                event.setSisaHari(json.getInt(AppConfig.TAG_SISA_HARI));
                event.setImageUrl(json.getString(AppConfig.TAG_IMAGE_URL));



            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            listEvent.add(event);
        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        //Finally initializing our adapter

    }
    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    class RecyclerTouchListener implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener{
        private GestureDetector mGestureDetector;
        private ClickListener mClickListener;


        public RecyclerTouchListener(final Context context, final RecyclerView recyclerView, final ClickListener clickListener) {
            this.mClickListener = clickListener;
            mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context,new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener(){
                @Override
                public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
                    return true;
                }

                @Override
                public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
                    View child = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(),e.getY());
                    if (child!=null && clickListener!=null){
                        clickListener.onLongClick(child, recyclerView.getChildAdapterPosition(child));
                    }
                    super.onLongPress(e);
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
            View child = rv.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
            if (child!=null && mClickListener!=null && mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)){
                mClickListener.onClick(child, rv.getChildAdapterPosition(child));
            }
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

        }
    }

    private boolean isLastItemDisplaying(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        if (recyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount() != 0) {
            int lastVisibleItemPosition = ((LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager()).findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
            if (lastVisibleItemPosition != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION && lastVisibleItemPosition == recyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount() - 1)
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    private RecyclerView.OnScrollListener rVOnScrollListener = new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener(){
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView,
                                         int newState) {
            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
//            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
//                    Config.DATA_URL+String.valueOf(requestCount), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
            if (isLastItemDisplaying(recyclerView)) {
//Calling the method getdata again
                getData();
            }

        }
    };
    public static interface ClickListener{
        public void onClick(View view, int position);
        public void onLongClick(View view, int position);
    }
    /**
     * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
     * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
     * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
     * activity.
     * <p>
     * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
     * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
     * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
     */
    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }



}
```

I dont know where is the error cause if I dont use on scroll change listener and just fetch all json data it is worked.
i use tutorial from this link https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-feed-example-using-php-mysql-volley/
and I want to change it to fragment

Comment: What's on line 163 of your `EventFragment` class?

Comment: that is the method to parse json data

Comment: I use tutorial from this link https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-feed-example-using-php-mysql-volley/ and I want to change it to fragment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move ProgressBar bind line to **onCreateView()**:

```
private ProgressBar progressBar;
```

Code should like:

```
View x =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_event,null);
progressBar = (ProgressBar) x.findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
```

**Reason:** Every widgets of **Fragment** would be bind with `rootView` of **Fragment**.

**Edit 1:**

Remove below line:

```
getActivity().getParent().setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: thanks for try but it still give me the same error nullpointer exeception. getDataFromServer(EventFragment.java:160), getData(EventFragment.java:192), onCreateView(EventFragment.java:127)

Comment: @PhilipusSilaen, I have edited my answer, please check

Comment: but if I move it to on create view method private JsonArrayRequest getDataFromServer(int requestCount) cannot access the progressBar

Comment: @PhilipusSilaen, Edited, please check

Comment: @PhilipusSilaen, make global variable with private modifier.

Comment: ya i've tried it, but still give me the same crash error nullpointer exeception

Comment: @PhilipusSilaen, I have edit answer with Edit 1: please remove that line

Comment: is it possible if the error cause the getData method? I've already stuck

Comment: @PhilipusSilaen, Call getData(); method on onActivityCreated()

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105881/discussion-between-hiren-patel-and-philipus-silaen).

Comment: WOW!!! you're really my savior. it worked now. Thanks so much. the method on getData() have no problem. it is because the progressbar. thanks so much!!!

Comment: @PhilipusSilaen, okay :)

Comment: bro Hiren patel, is it possible if i'm using swipe refresh layout instead of onchange listener? so this code  if (isLastItemDisplaying(recyclerView)) {
                //Calling the method getdata again
                getData();
            } will be inside on refresh listener?

Comment: sorry if im asking too much hehe

Comment: @PhilipusSilaen, please come to chat

Comment: bro @HirenPatel im sorry if im asking again, but I really need help. im already read the reference that you give but im too newbie, here is my link to my new quoestion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35960836/why-recycleview-data-cannot-sync-with-data-from-server-side-database