# Why recycleview data cannot sync with data from server side database

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-volley, android-recyclerview

I am using restapi to provide data to my app in android and for the database I am using phpmyadmin and do it in localhost, everything goes well, but when I am adding new data in database my `recycleview` cannot sync with newest data in database so when I swipe or scroll the newest data that I have just added appear as double in my `recycleview` and it will never end. I am using an emulator to run the apk.

If anyone can help me fix my code I really appreciate it. Here is my `customVolleyRequest` code:

```
public class CustomVolleyRequest {

    private static CustomVolleyRequest customVolleyRequest;
    private static Context context;
    private RequestQueue requestQueue;
    private ImageLoader imageLoader;

    private CustomVolleyRequest(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        this.requestQueue = getRequestQueue();

        imageLoader = new ImageLoader(requestQueue,
                new ImageLoader.ImageCache() {
                    private final LruCache<String, Bitmap>
                            cache = new LruCache<String, Bitmap>(20);

                    @Override
                    public Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
                        return cache.get(url);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void putBitmap(String url, Bitmap bitmap) {
                        cache.put(url, bitmap);
                    }
                });
    }

    public static synchronized CustomVolleyRequest getInstance(Context context) {
        if (customVolleyRequest == null) {
            customVolleyRequest = new CustomVolleyRequest(context);
        }
        return customVolleyRequest;
    }

    public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
        if (requestQueue == null) {
            Cache cache = new DiskBasedCache(context.getCacheDir(), 10 * 1024 * 1024);
            Network network = new BasicNetwork(new HurlStack());
            requestQueue = new RequestQueue(cache, network);
            requestQueue.start();
        }
        return requestQueue;
    }

    public ImageLoader getImageLoader() {
        return imageLoader;
    }
}
```

This is my `appconfig` class for storing tag:

```
public class AppConfig {
    // Server user login url
    public static String URL_LOGIN = "http://192.168.0.13:80/task_manager/v1/login";

    // Server user register url
    public static String URL_REGISTER = "http://192.168.0.13/task_manager/v1/register";

    //URL of my even
    public static final String DATA_URL = "http://192.168.0.13/task_manager/v1/even/";

    //Tags for my JSON

    public static final String TAG_IMAGE_URL = "gambar";
    public static final String TAG_JUDUL = "judul";
    public static final String TAG_DESKRIPSI = "deskripsi";
    public static final String TAG_DUIT = "duit";
    public static final String TAG_PERSEN = "persen";
    public static final String TAG_SISA_HARI = "sisahari";
}
```

This is getter and setter:

```
public class Event {
        //Data Variables
        private String imageUrl;
        private String name;
        private String rank;
        private int realName;
        private int createdBy;
        private int firstAppearance;
        //private ArrayList<String> powers;

        //Getters and Setters
        public String getImageUrl() {
            return imageUrl;
        }

        public void setImageUrl(String imageUrl) {
            this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
        }

        //GET AND SET JUDUL
        public String getJudul() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setJudul(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        //GET AND SET DESKRIPSI
        public String getDeskripsi() {
            return rank;
        }

        public void setDeskripsi(String rank) {
            this.rank = rank;
        }

        //GET AND SET DUIT

        public int getDuit() {
            return realName;
        }

        public void setDuit(int realName) {
            this.realName = realName;
        }

        //GET AND SET PERSEN

        public int getPersen() {
            return createdBy;
        }

        public void setPersen(int createdBy) {
            this.createdBy = createdBy;
        }

        //GET AND SET SISA HARI

        public int getSisaHari() {
            return firstAppearance;
        }

        public void setSisaHari(int firstAppearance) {
            this.firstAppearance = firstAppearance;
        }
    }
```

And this is my main fragment:

```
package com.anakacara.anakacara.Fragment;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;
import android.support.v7.widget.DefaultItemAnimator;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.anakacara.anakacara.App.AppConfig;
import com.anakacara.anakacara.App.Event;
import com.anakacara.anakacara.Helper.CardAdapter;
import com.anakacara.anakacara.R;
import com.anakacara.anakacara.activity.DetailEvent;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonArrayRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Activities that contain this fragment must implement the
 * {@link EventFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener} interface
 * to handle interaction events.
 * Use the {@link EventFragment#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
public class EventFragment extends Fragment implements SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener {
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    //Creating a List of event
    private List<Event> listEvent;

    //Creating Views
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
    private int requestCount = 1;
    private int list;
    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;
    private RequestQueue requestQueue;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;
    public EventFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment EventFragment.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static EventFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        EventFragment fragment = new EventFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    private final RecyclerView.OnScrollListener onScrollListener = new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(final RecyclerView recyclerView, final int newState) {
            // code

        }

        @Override
        public void onScrolled(final RecyclerView recyclerView, final int dx, final int dy) {
            // code
            if (isLastItemDisplaying(recyclerView)) {
                //Calling the method getdata again
                getData();
            }
        }
    };
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View x =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_event,null);;
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) x.findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) x.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        listEvent = new ArrayList<>();
        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());

        swipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) x.findViewById(R.id.swipeRefreshLayout);
        swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);

        /**
         * Showing Swipe Refresh animation on activity create
         * As animation won't start on onCreate, post runnable is used
         */
        swipeRefreshLayout.post(new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);

                                        getData();

                                    }
                                }
        );

        // listEvent = new ArrayList<>();
        // requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
        //Calling method to get data
        //this method is called twice as if you see
        // getData();

//        swipeRefreshLayout= (SwipeRefreshLayout) x.findViewById(R.id.swipeRefreshLayout);
//        swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener()
//        {
//            @Override
//            public void onRefresh()
//            {
//                if (isLastItemDisplaying(recyclerView)) {
////Calling the method getdata again
//                    getData();
//                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
//                }
//            }
//        });
        recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(rVOnScrollListener);
        adapter = new CardAdapter(listEvent, getActivity());

        //Adding adapter to recyclerview
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        RecyclerView.ItemAnimator itemAnimator = new DefaultItemAnimator();
        itemAnimator.setAddDuration(1000);
        itemAnimator.setRemoveDuration(1000);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(itemAnimator);
        recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerTouchListener(getActivity(), recyclerView, new ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view, int position) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), DetailEvent.class);
                intent.putExtra("event_judul", listEvent.get(position).getJudul()); //you can name the keys whatever you like
                intent.putExtra("event_deskripsi", listEvent.get(position).getDeskripsi()); //note that all these values have to be primitive (i.e boolean, int, double, String, etc.)
                intent.putExtra("event_duit", listEvent.get(position).getDuit());
                intent.putExtra("event_persen", listEvent.get(position).getPersen()); //note that all these values have to be primitive (i.e boolean, int, double, String, etc.)
                intent.putExtra("event_sisa_hari", listEvent.get(position).getSisaHari());
                intent.putExtra("event_image", listEvent.get(position).getImageUrl());
                startActivity(intent);
            }

            @Override
            public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Kepencet Lama " + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }));

        return x;
    }
    private JsonArrayRequest getDataFromServer(int requestCount) {
        //Initializing ProgressBar

        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
        //Displaying Progressbar
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
//        getActivity().getParent().setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);

        //JsonArrayRequest of volley
        JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(AppConfig.DATA_URL + String.valueOf(requestCount),
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        //Calling method parseData to parse the json response
                        parseData(response);

                        //Hiding the progressbar
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        //If an error occurs that means end of the list has reached
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No More Items Available"+list, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                    }
                });

        //Returning the request
        return jsonArrayRequest;
    }

    private void getData() {
        //Adding the method to the queue by calling the method getDataFromServer

        requestQueue.add(getDataFromServer(requestCount));
        //Incrementing the request counter


    }

    //This method will parse json data

    private void parseData(JSONArray array) {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
            Event event = new Event();
            JSONObject json = null;
            try {
                json = array.getJSONObject(i);

                event.setJudul(json.getString(AppConfig.TAG_JUDUL));
                event.setDeskripsi(json.getString(AppConfig.TAG_DESKRIPSI));
                event.setDuit(json.getInt(AppConfig.TAG_DUIT));
                event.setPersen(json.getInt(AppConfig.TAG_PERSEN));
                event.setSisaHari(json.getInt(AppConfig.TAG_SISA_HARI));
                event.setImageUrl(json.getString(AppConfig.TAG_IMAGE_URL));
                event.setTotal(json.getInt(AppConfig.TAG_TOTAL));


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            listEvent.add(event);
        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        if( requestCount <= listEvent.get(0).getTotal())    {
            requestCount++;
        }


        //Finally initializing our adapter

    }
    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onRefresh() {
        if (isLastItemDisplaying(recyclerView)) {
            getData();
        }
    }


    class RecyclerTouchListener implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener{
        private GestureDetector mGestureDetector;
        private ClickListener mClickListener;


        public RecyclerTouchListener(final Context context, final RecyclerView recyclerView, final ClickListener clickListener) {
            this.mClickListener = clickListener;
            mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context,new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener(){
                @Override
                public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
                    return true;
                }

                @Override
                public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
                    View child = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(),e.getY());
                    if (child!=null && clickListener!=null){
                        clickListener.onLongClick(child, recyclerView.getChildAdapterPosition(child));
                    }
                    super.onLongPress(e);
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
            View child = rv.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
            if (child!=null && mClickListener!=null && mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)){
                mClickListener.onClick(child, rv.getChildAdapterPosition(child));
            }
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

        }
    }

    private boolean isLastItemDisplaying(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        if (recyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount() != 0) {
            int lastVisibleItemPosition = ((LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager()).findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
            if (lastVisibleItemPosition != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION && lastVisibleItemPosition == recyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount() - 1)
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    private RecyclerView.OnScrollListener rVOnScrollListener = new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener(){
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView,
                                         int newState) {
            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
//            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
//                    Config.DATA_URL+String.valueOf(requestCount), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
            if (isLastItemDisplaying(recyclerView)) {
//Calling the method getdata again
                getData();
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

        }
    };
    public static interface ClickListener{
        public void onClick(View view, int position);
        public void onLongClick(View view, int position);
    }
    /**
     * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
     * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
     * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
     * activity.
     * <p>
     * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
     * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
     * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
     */
    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }
}
```

Here is my adapter:

```
package com.anakacara.anakacara.Helper;

/**
 * Created by Philipus on 05/03/2016.
 */

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.anakacara.anakacara.App.CustomVolleyRequest;
import com.anakacara.anakacara.App.Event;
import com.anakacara.anakacara.R;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Belal on 11/9/2015.
 */
public class CardAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CardAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private ImageLoader imageLoader;
    private Context context;

    //List of eventes
    List<Event> eventes;

    public CardAdapter(List<Event> eventes, Context context){
        super();
        //Getting all the eventA
        this.eventes = eventes;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.event_list, parent, false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        Event event =  eventes.get(position);

        imageLoader = CustomVolleyRequest.getInstance(context).getImageLoader();
        imageLoader.get(event.getImageUrl(), ImageLoader.getImageListener(holder.imageView, R.mipmap.ic_launcher, android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert));

        holder.imageView.setImageUrl(event.getImageUrl(), imageLoader);
        holder.textViewJudul.setText(event.getJudul());
        holder.textViewRank.setText(event.getDeskripsi());
        holder.textViewRealName.setText(String.valueOf(event.getDuit()));
        holder.textViewCreatedBy.setText(String.valueOf(event.getPersen()));
        holder.textViewFirstAppearance.setText(String.valueOf(event.getSisaHari()));


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return eventes.size();
    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public NetworkImageView imageView;
        public TextView textViewJudul;
        public TextView textViewRank;
        public TextView textViewRealName;
        public TextView textViewCreatedBy;
        public TextView textViewFirstAppearance;
//        public TextView  textViewPowers;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            imageView = (NetworkImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewHero);
            textViewJudul = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewJudul);
            textViewRank= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewRank);
            textViewRealName= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewRealName);
            textViewCreatedBy= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewCreatedBy);
            textViewFirstAppearance= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewFirstAppearance);

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use onRequestFinishedLitener of Volley queue to notifay data set changed.

```
class RequestListener implements RequestQueue.RequestFinishedListener {

        @Override
        public void onRequestFinished(Request request) {
   adapter.notifyDatasetChanged();

     }
}
```

Then

```
RequestListener rl = new RequestListener();
volley_queue.addRequestFinishedListener(listener);
```

if you want to load new data when list comes to the end. you will have to make pages in your API which lying on server. you will have to access page by page. As per the list reaches to end you call parseJson for next page.

you will have call your parseJSON method with new link which contains next data. For this you will have add OnScrollListener of ReyclerView.

```
 class RecyclerViewOnScroll extends RecyclerView.OnScrollListener
    {
        int temp_page_position;
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
            if ((list.size()-1 == layoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition())) {  
  // Enters to block when last item of RecyclerView has appeared.
}
}
}
```

Comment: where i should put it? on customvolleyrequest class?

Comment: you can make a nested class which implements RequestFinishedListene, where adapter should be accessible inside nested class. and add listner to queue as shown in answer.

Comment: Add on scroll in the class from where your data list is accessible as told in Answer

Comment: i've already done that. look at my mainfragment, each page have 2 item. and i've already have this method private boolean isLastItemDisplaying(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        if (recyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount() != 0) {
            int lastVisibleItemPosition = ((LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager()).findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
            if (lastVisibleItemPosition != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION && lastVisibleItemPosition == recyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount() - 1)
                return true;
        }

Comment: why notifydatasetchanged error when i use that as nested class in my mainfragment?

Comment: ok., are you notifying in onRequestFinished() ?  what is error message ? i