# how to handle Requestcount++ url recycleview volley

Tags: android, android-fragments, while-loop, android-volley, android-recyclerview

im load data from my rest api using url in my main fragment. here is my url "http://192.168.0.13/task_manager/v1/even/" when user scroll or swipe he will load "http://192.168.0.13/task_manager/v1/even/ + page number, in here requestcount++. so each url give me 2 item.and when we scroll again will get same url with requestcount++. how can I limit my request count? so when the api for example only have item until url/4. so when it error it will keep load that url/4. and when i add new item so the url/5 have item the requestcount++ will active again
can i use code like this?

```
while(!Response.ErrorListener){
            requestCount++;
        }
```

so when it doenst counter errorlistener in json array request it will requestCount++

and this is my main fragment

```
package com.anakacara.anakacara.Fragment;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;
import android.support.v7.widget.DefaultItemAnimator;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.anakacara.anakacara.App.AppConfig;
import com.anakacara.anakacara.App.Event;
import com.anakacara.anakacara.Helper.CardAdapter;
import com.anakacara.anakacara.R;
import com.anakacara.anakacara.activity.DetailEvent;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonArrayRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Activities that contain this fragment must implement the
 * {@link EventFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener} interface
 * to handle interaction events.
 * Use the {@link EventFragment#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
public class EventFragment extends Fragment implements SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener {
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    //Creating a List of event
    private List<Event> listEvent;

    //Creating Views
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
    **private int requestCount = 1;**
    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;
    private RequestQueue requestQueue;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;
    public EventFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment EventFragment.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static EventFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        EventFragment fragment = new EventFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    private final RecyclerView.OnScrollListener onScrollListener = new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(final RecyclerView recyclerView, final int newState) {
            // code
            if (isLastItemDisplaying(recyclerView)) {
                //Calling the method getdata again
                getData();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onScrolled(final RecyclerView recyclerView, final int dx, final int dy) {
            // code
            if (isLastItemDisplaying(recyclerView)) {
                //Calling the method getdata again
                getData();
            }
        }
    };
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View x =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_event,null);;
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) x.findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) x.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        swipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) x.findViewById(R.id.swipeRefreshLayout);
        swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);

        /**
         * Showing Swipe Refresh animation on activity create
         * As animation won't start on onCreate, post runnable is used
         */
        swipeRefreshLayout.post(new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);

                                        getData();
                                    }
                                }
        );




        //Initializing our event list
        listEvent = new ArrayList<>();
        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
        //Calling method to get data
        getData();

//        swipeRefreshLayout= (SwipeRefreshLayout) x.findViewById(R.id.swipeRefreshLayout);
//        swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener()
//        {
//            @Override
//            public void onRefresh()
//            {
//                if (isLastItemDisplaying(recyclerView)) {
////Calling the method getdata again
//                    getData();
//                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
//                }
//            }
//        });
        recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(rVOnScrollListener);
        adapter = new CardAdapter(listEvent, getActivity());

        //Adding adapter to recyclerview
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        RecyclerView.ItemAnimator itemAnimator = new DefaultItemAnimator();
        itemAnimator.setAddDuration(1000);
        itemAnimator.setRemoveDuration(1000);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(itemAnimator);
        recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerTouchListener(getActivity(), recyclerView, new ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view, int position) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), DetailEvent.class);
                intent.putExtra("event_judul", listEvent.get(position).getJudul()); //you can name the keys whatever you like
                intent.putExtra("event_deskripsi", listEvent.get(position).getDeskripsi()); //note that all these values have to be primitive (i.e boolean, int, double, String, etc.)
                intent.putExtra("event_duit", listEvent.get(position).getDuit());
                intent.putExtra("event_persen", listEvent.get(position).getPersen()); //note that all these values have to be primitive (i.e boolean, int, double, String, etc.)
                intent.putExtra("event_sisa_hari", listEvent.get(position).getSisaHari());
                intent.putExtra("event_image", listEvent.get(position).getImageUrl());
                startActivity(intent);
            }

            @Override
            public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Kepencet Lama " + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }));

        return x;
    }
    private JsonArrayRequest getDataFromServer(int requestCount) {
        //Initializing ProgressBar

        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
        //Displaying Progressbar
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
//        getActivity().getParent().setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);

        //JsonArrayRequest of volley
        JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(AppConfig.DATA_URL + String.valueOf(**requestCount**),
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        //Calling method parseData to parse the json response
                        parseData(response);
                        //Hiding the progressbar
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        //If an error occurs that means end of the list has reached
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No More Items Available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                    }
                });

        //Returning the request
        return jsonArrayRequest;
    }

    private void getData() {
        //Adding the method to the queue by calling the method getDataFromServer

        requestQueue.add(getDataFromServer(**requestCount**));
        //Incrementing the request counter
        **requestCount++;**

    }

    //This method will parse json data
    private void parseData(JSONArray array) {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
            Event event = new Event();
            JSONObject json = null;
            try {
                json = array.getJSONObject(i);

                event.setJudul(json.getString(AppConfig.TAG_JUDUL));
                event.setDeskripsi(json.getString(AppConfig.TAG_DESKRIPSI));
                event.setDuit(json.getInt(AppConfig.TAG_DUIT));
                event.setPersen(json.getInt(AppConfig.TAG_PERSEN));
                event.setSisaHari(json.getInt(AppConfig.TAG_SISA_HARI));
                event.setImageUrl(json.getString(AppConfig.TAG_IMAGE_URL));


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            listEvent.add(event);
        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        //Finally initializing our adapter

    }
    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onRefresh() {
        getData();
    }


    class RecyclerTouchListener implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener{
        private GestureDetector mGestureDetector;
        private ClickListener mClickListener;


        public RecyclerTouchListener(final Context context, final RecyclerView recyclerView, final ClickListener clickListener) {
            this.mClickListener = clickListener;
            mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context,new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener(){
                @Override
                public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
                    return true;
                }

                @Override
                public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
                    View child = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(),e.getY());
                    if (child!=null && clickListener!=null){
                        clickListener.onLongClick(child, recyclerView.getChildAdapterPosition(child));
                    }
                    super.onLongPress(e);
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
            View child = rv.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
            if (child!=null && mClickListener!=null && mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)){
                mClickListener.onClick(child, rv.getChildAdapterPosition(child));
            }
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

        }
    }

    private boolean isLastItemDisplaying(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        if (recyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount() != 0) {
            int lastVisibleItemPosition = ((LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager()).findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
            if (lastVisibleItemPosition != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION && lastVisibleItemPosition == recyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount() - 1)
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    private RecyclerView.OnScrollListener rVOnScrollListener = new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener(){
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView,
                                         int newState) {
            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
//            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
//                    Config.DATA_URL+String.valueOf(requestCount), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
            if (isLastItemDisplaying(recyclerView)) {
//Calling the method getdata again
                getData();
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

        }
    };
    public static interface ClickListener{
        public void onClick(View view, int position);
        public void onLongClick(View view, int position);
    }
    /**
     * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
     * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
     * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
     * activity.
     * <p>
     * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
     * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
     * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
     */
    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }



}
```

here is my adapter

```
package com.anakacara.anakacara.Helper;

/**
 * Created by Philipus on 05/03/2016.
 */

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.anakacara.anakacara.App.CustomVolleyRequest;
import com.anakacara.anakacara.App.Event;
import com.anakacara.anakacara.R;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Belal on 11/9/2015.
 */
public class CardAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CardAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private ImageLoader imageLoader;
    private Context context;

    //List of eventes
    List<Event> eventes;

    public CardAdapter(List<Event> eventes, Context context){
        super();
        //Getting all the eventA
        this.eventes = eventes;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.event_list, parent, false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        Event event =  eventes.get(position);

        imageLoader = CustomVolleyRequest.getInstance(context).getImageLoader();
        imageLoader.get(event.getImageUrl(), ImageLoader.getImageListener(holder.imageView, R.mipmap.ic_launcher, android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert));

        holder.imageView.setImageUrl(event.getImageUrl(), imageLoader);
        holder.textViewJudul.setText(event.getJudul());
        holder.textViewRank.setText(event.getDeskripsi());
        holder.textViewRealName.setText(String.valueOf(event.getDuit()));
        holder.textViewCreatedBy.setText(String.valueOf(event.getPersen()));
        holder.textViewFirstAppearance.setText(String.valueOf(event.getSisaHari()));


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return eventes.size();
    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public NetworkImageView imageView;
        public TextView textViewJudul;
        public TextView textViewRank;
        public TextView textViewRealName;
        public TextView textViewCreatedBy;
        public TextView textViewFirstAppearance;
//        public TextView  textViewPowers;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            imageView = (NetworkImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewHero);
            textViewJudul = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewJudul);
            textViewRank= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewRank);
            textViewRealName= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewRealName);
            textViewCreatedBy= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewCreatedBy);
            textViewFirstAppearance= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewFirstAppearance);

        }


    }
}
```

Comment: You can add variable for total page count and then before calling check if counter is lower then page count then call otherwise don't make call just display message to user.

Comment: im get your idea. and im using this listEvent.get(1).getTotal()) to get page limit from my api. but error indexoutof bound exeception. do you know why? @androidnoobdev

Comment: can you paste your json so i can understand what is listEvent.get(1).getTotal()) ?

Comment: thx bro, i've already solved it but now the problem is my recycleview dont sync with my database in server side

Comment: your welcome, can you elobrate your new problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35960836/why-recycleview-data-cannot-sync-with-data-from-server-side-database here my problem